# How to send data to server in Retrofit Android

Tags: android, retrofit

In my application I want send some data to server with `@Body` and I used **Retrofit** library. 
In body class I have 2 items, **ID** and **NAME**. 
When **ID** is **filled**, I should send just **ID** and **not send NAME** and when **NAME** is **filled**, I should send just **NAME** again **not send ID**! 
**Body model is:**

```
data class BodyUserData(
    @SerializedName("types")
    var types: MutableList<Types?>? = null
) {
    data class Types(
        @SerializedName("name")
        var naName: String? = null,
        @SerializedName("id")
        var id: String? = null
    )
}
```

**Api services codes:**

```
@PATCH("update-data")
suspend fun updateUserData(@Header("Authorization") token: String, @Body body: BodyUserData):
        Response<ResponseUserData>
```

And I write below codes in activity for fill data:

```
RxBus.listen(RxEvents.TypesListEvent::class.java).subscribe {
    val typesList: MutableList<BodyUserData.Type?> = mutableListOf()
    it.data.forEach { item ->
        if (item.id == 0) {
            typesList.add(BodyUserData.Type(name = item.name))
        } else {
            typesList.add(BodyUserData.Type(id = item.id.toString()))
        }
    }
    body.type = typesList
}
```

After call Api and see send data in logcat show me body data such as below:

```
{"types":[{"name":"cars","id":null},{"name":null,"id":"1791538835"},{"name":null,"id":"1812286134"}]}
```

In above Json send null data but I want when data is null not send to server.
True Json is such as this:

```
{"types":[{"name":"cars"},{"id":"1791538835"},{"id":"1812286134"}]}
```

How can I it?

Comment: can you show me your ConverterFactory? it is used when you create retrofit client

Comment: @ArvinRezaei I used Gson

Comment: do you use serializeNulls() when you create your GsonBuilder ? can you post it here ?

Comment: @ArvinRezaei `fun provideGson(): Gson = GsonBuilder().setLenient().serializeNulls().create()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most remove **serializeNulls()** from your GsonBuilder that you pass to **ConverterFactory** of your retrofit so it avoid serialize null values.

Comment: Thanks, can you send to me code for how can I pass it to Converter factory? Your mean is this ? : `addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))`

Comment: in your code , just remove the serializeNulls() in below part:
fun provideGson(): Gson = GsonBuilder().setLenient().serializeNulls().create() 
to
fun provideGson(): Gson = GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()

Answer (score 0):

You can deal with it using `MultipartBody`

**Api services codes:** (paid attention to `@Body body : RequestBody`)

```
@PATCH("update-data")
suspend fun updateUserData(@Header("Authorization") token: String, @Body body : RequestBody): Response<ResponseUserData>
```

In Your activity

```kotlin
RxBus.listen(RxEvents.TypesListEvent::class.java).subscribe {
    val builder = MultipartBody.Builder().apply { setType(MultipartBody.FORM) }
    it.data.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
        if (item.id == 0) {
            builder.addFormDataPart("types[$index][name]", item.name)
        } else {
            builder.addFormDataPart("types[$index][id]", item.id.toString())
        }
    }
    val requestBody = builder.build() // Here you will get request body corresponding to your needs
}
```